# Comparison of 1 outcome between 2 groups

Tags: r, logistic

I have a question about logistic regression.

I have 2 groups in my database defined by a variable named "ttt".
I want to compare one variable named "w36_oxy" between the 2 groups, with an adjustment with 2 variables "pre_ste" and "g_age".

I tried this but I am not sure it is the result I want :

```
summary(glm(as.factor(w36_oxy) ~ ttt + g_age + pre_ste, 
            data=data_dysplasie2, family=binomial))
```

I think the solution might be but I'm not sure :

```
summary(glm(as.factor(ttt) ~ w36_oxy + g_age + pre_ste, 
        data=data_dysplasie2, family=binomial))
```

Comment: What are w36_oxy and ttt?  Are they categorical or numeric or what? 

But your first model is closer to what you asked for,  since w36_oxy is the outcome. Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: They are binary variables. 
Actually, I want to know if there is a difference between 2 groups defined by the variable "ttt" for "w36_oxy" outcome, with an adjustment with "pre_ste" (binary) and "g_age" (continuous).
I think it is wrong because the "ttt" variable is a variable the model adjust on and I'm not sure it is what should be done.

Comment: what do you mean by *compare*?  Depends on what exactly you want. eg Look at the odds ratio prior to invoking the control variables. Then you need to use logistic regression to invoke the control variables. The response variable will be defined by what you need. Thus both the models are okay. The interpretation will differ

Comment: I mean know in which ttt group there are more w36_oxy than the other controlling for g_age and "pre_ste".